# Gradle maven-publish dependency scope

Tags: gradle, dependencies, transitive-dependency, maven-publish

I have a pretty simple Gradle Kotlin project.

```
plugins {
    id 'application'
    id 'maven-publish'
}

repositories { mavenCentral() }

dependencies {
     compile 'com.google.guava:guava:31.1-jre'      // 'compile' is deprecated
}

publishing {
    publications {
        maven(MavenPublication) {
            groupId = 'de.mabe'; artifactId = 'project1'; version = '1.0'
            from components.java
        }
    }
}
```

When I start `gradle publishToMavenLocal` it generates a correct `pom` file with a correct dependency:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.google.guava</groupId>
    <artifactId>guava</artifactId>
    <version>31.1-jre</version>
    <scope>compile</scope>             <!-- this scope is important -->
</dependency>
```

Now I replaced the `compile` with `implementation` in the gradle script.

```
implementation 'com.google.guava:guava:31.1-jre'
```

Unexpectedly this changes the scope in the `pom` file from `compile` to `runtime`.

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.google.guava</groupId>
    <artifactId>guava</artifactId>
    <version>31.1-jre</version>
    <scope>runtime</scope>             <!-- compile EXPECTED ?!?! -->
</dependency>
```

What do I have to do to get the previous `pom` back?

Comment: Did you try `compileOnly` scope?

Comment: When using `compileOnly` the dependency is not in the `pom` at all.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That is by design. The semantics of the `implementation` configuration is to declare dependencies that are internal to a module. By mapping it to the `runtime` scope of a Maven pom, it ensures that it doesn't leak onto the compilation classpath of consumers. This has a few advantages like being more free to swap out transitive depencies with less risk of affecting consuming modules, to make compilation faster and more.

If you need to make a transitive dependency part of the `compile` scope, i.e. expose it on the compilation classpath of consuming projects, you need to use the `api` configuration instead. This is available by applying the `java-library` plugin.

For example (Groovy DSL):

```java
plugins {
    id 'java-library'
    id 'maven-publish'
}

dependencies {
    implementation 'org.apache.commons:commons-math3:3.6.1' // <- Maps to the Maven runtime scope 
    api 'com.google.guava:guava:30.1.1-jre' // <- Maps to the Maven compile scope
}

publishing {
    publications {
        maven(MavenPublication) {
            groupId = 'de.mabe'; artifactId = 'project1'; version = '1.0'
            from components.java
        }
    }
}
```

You can read more about the separation between API and implementation in the Gradle user guide [here](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/java_library_plugin.html#sec:java_library_separation).